# How to access files in outside of bin folder in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am developing a web app in ASP.net Core MVC and am trying to access a TempFile in a folder called TempFile within my project.

```
MyWebAPP:.
├───TempFiles
     ├─── file.wav
```

However I cannot access that file, even tho it exists, through JavaScript, like this:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/SandboxHub").build();

// Start the SignalR connection
connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err));

// Handle textbox change event
$("#sentence-input").on("input", async function () {
    // Get the sentence value
    const sentence = $(this).val();

    // Send the sentence to the Hub
    await connection.invoke("TransformIntoTTS", sentence);

    connection.on("ReceiveFile", function (fileUrl) {
        const relativeFilePath = fileUrl.replace("/LearningWithAI-WebLayer", "");


        // Apply the file URL to the source of the audio controller
        $("#audio-player").attr("src", "../" + relativeFilePath);

    });
});
```

Comment: Have you used Static Files in your ASP.NET Core project - something like `app.UseStaticFiles()`? By default they will not be served. I'm guessing you get a 404 Not Found.

Comment: Yes, I do use app.UseStaticFiles() @phuzi

Comment: Can you include these details in your question? Can you confirm what error you're getting from ASP.NET Core

Comment: @phuzi Im not getting an exception but in the Browser console, I get a GET 404 error

Comment: So you are getting an error from ASP.NET Core!

Comment: @phuzi No. THe issue is not on the backend. The issue is that I cannot access the file from my javascript because I might be approaching the file path wrong that I am unaware.

Comment: In that case then, we need you to do some basic debugging. You haven't told us what URL the JS trying to access? How does that compare with what you're expecting? etc.?

Comment: @phuzi The url js is trying to access is '\\TempFiles\\fileName.wav'. I am expecting it to attach that audio to the <audio> element src.

Comment: It looks like a backend configuration error. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-static-files) _"The default directory is {content root}/wwwroot_" - you're either going to move your tempfiles to wwwroot or override the default config.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you could try to create the folder inside the wwwroot folder instead of using the project's default web root folder, since only wwwroot folder inside the asp.net core could be accessed by the client.

If you want to serve files outside of web root, you should try to use below codes:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "TempFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/TempFiles"
});
```

More details about how static files works inside asp.net core, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0).